# CSS-based layout equivalent of HTML-based table

Tags: html, css

I want a CSS solution (in principle HTML5/CSS3) that would reproduce the behaviour of the following table-based layout:

```html
<table width="80%" align="center" border="1">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>Some content that varies in size</td>
    <td width="200">Maybe an image, maybe some short text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My best attempt with CSS gets me the left-side contents (the "content that varies in size" above) to wrap around the div on the right.

Here's what I'm trying:

```css
div.outsidecontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div.absolute {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
div.filler {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outsidecontainer">
  <div class="absolute">This is the fixed-size div on the right</div>
  <div class="filler">Another div element with a lot of text .....</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acomplish this in a few ways.

Instead of using float right to get the content on the right, just place it on the right. With `float: left;` on each of the containers contents and placing a `clearfix:both;` in the bottom of the container:
**Your approach - fixed**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outsidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  float: left;
}

.absolute {
  width: 200px;
}

.filler {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
}
/*used to stop the container from collapsing*/
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="outsidecontainer">
  <div class="filler cell">Another div element with a lot of text .....</div>
  <div class="absolute cell">This is the fixed-size div on the right</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use the `display: table` to replicate a table using divs.

**display: table Approach**

```css
.t-body {
  width: 80%;
  display: table;
}

.t-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.t-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fw {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-body">
  <div class="t-row">
    <div class="t-cell">Another div element with a lot of text ....</div>
    <div class="t-cell fw">This is the fixed-size div on the right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a common pattern is to set the parent ("outsidecontainer" in this case) to `position: relative` then the child element ("absolute") to `position: absolute` and `right: 0`.  This pattern set's a `position: absolute` child elements to be constrained to the boundaries of the parent element (rather than being constrained by default to boundaries of the 'body' element)

this is an alternative to `float: right` (which would also work)

then set `margin-right` to compensate for the width of the "absolute" div

```css
div.outsidecontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
} 

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /* position to the right of "outsidecontainer" div */
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div.filler
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 200px; /* compensate for "absolute" div's width */
}
```

```html
<div class="outsidecontainer">
  <div class="absolute">
    <p>This is the fixed-size div on the right</p>
    <p>This is the fixed-size div on the right</p>
    <p>This is the fixed-size div on the right</p>
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
    <p>Another div element with a lot of text ..... </p>
    <p>Another div element with a lot of text ..... </p>
    <p>Another div element with a lot of text ..... </p>
    <p>Another div element with a lot of text ..... </p>
    <p>Another div element with a lot of text ..... </p>
    <p>Another div element with a lot of text ..... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```